# Spark-on-k8s handling Pending & Completed executor pods

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming

Have been doing POC with Spark streaming jobs on Spark-on-k8s, and most cases are working fine on scale setups having no resource constraints.

Used the following spark-submit in `client` mode:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --master k8s://https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --name ${APP_NAME} \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=1  \
  --conf spark.driver.ip=$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST \
  --conf spark.driver.host=${POD_IP} \
  --conf spark.logConf=true \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=$IMAGE \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=$SERVICEACCOUNT \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=${HOSTNAME} \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=${EXECUTOR_PREFIX} \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination=true \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.appKillPodDeletionGracePeriod=60s \
  --conf spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown=true \
  --class ${MAIN_CLASS} $APPS_DIR/${APP_NAME}-${APP_VERSION}.jar $2
```

**Scenario-1:**
Running the pods in constraints setup having limited resources if the executor pod is in `Pending` state, the driver keeps creating new executor pods overloading the nodes, and affecting other pods. *How to limit the number of executors pods to 1*?

Driver & executor pods:

```
poc-spark-streaming-6666f8ddbd-q279q       0/1     Running
poc-spark-streaming-exec-1                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-3                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-4                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-5                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-7                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-2                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-8                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-9                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-10                0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-6                 0/1     Pending
poc-spark-streaming-exec-11                0/1     Pending
```

Executor pod event:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
    Warning  FailedScheduling  31s (x8 over 10m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient CPU.
```

**Scenario-2:** The executors pods are being collected after it is completed or if driver pods are manually deleted but in case if we have K8s `livenessProbe` enabled for the driver pod, the driver container restarts, it doesn't gracefully collect the associated executor pods and marks them as `Completed`. Have used the following configs:

```
spark.kubernetes.appKillPodDeletionGracePeriod 60s
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown true
spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination true
```

Driver pod log:

```
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker stopped
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator gracefully
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO JobGenerator: Waiting for all received blocks to be consumed for job generation
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO JobGenerator: Waited for all received blocks to be consumed for job generation
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster.
23/04/24 16:03:10 INFO SerialShutdownHooks: Successfully executed shutdown hook: Clearing session cache for C* connector
23/04/24 16:03:40 WARN ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
23/04/24 16:03:40 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.InterruptedException
```

Executor pods:

```
spark-device-streaming-7d8df4d8c7-p4w6c                     1/1     Running
spark-device-streaming-exec-1                               0/1     Completed
spark-device-streaming-exec-2                               0/1     Completed
```

```
Logs:
23/04/24 16:03:41 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver 10.3.45.116:45339 disassociated! Shutting down.
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver from 10.3.45.116:45339 disconnected during shutdown
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-7bc251da-6bcb-4f11-9f1d-691ad944f4da/spark-298dbb58-989f-48a5-b0be-5241178b805e
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster.
23/04/24 16:03:41 INFO SerialShutdownHooks: Successfully executed shutdown hook: Clearing session cache for C* connector
```

Any suggestion on the following:

1. Is there a native way to delete/cleanup the existing pending pods while creating new executor pods or how can we fix the number of executors to 1 in case of constraint setup so, the number of executor pods should not increase over time in case there are no resources?
2. How should we handle the graceful shutdown of executor pods in case of Scenario-2 when K8s `livenessProbe` fails and driver containers restart, creating a new executor pod?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414655/spark-on-kubernetes-executor-cleanup

Comment: @ArefRiant The executor pods are of  kind: Pod, the answer is applicable to K8s batch/jobs. I have also set the config deleteOnTermination to true for deletion of pods after termination/completion which works all cases except livenessProbe fails.